# Bank statement validity for UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-funds, proof-provenance-of-funds

When applying for a UK visa, how old should the bank statement be?

Answer (score 5):

The guidance says they should not be more than a year old. Ideally, you'll show several months of statements, so by definition most of them will be more than a month old.

See https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents:

> ## Section 4: documents you should not send unless  specifically requested
>
> This page provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to 
>   consider your application.
>
> - if you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide multiple copies 
>     of the same documents
> - bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of 
>     application
>
> ...

Comment: @Adil comments are not used for thanks, if you want to say thanks, please do it in the way the site describes! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers